Parametric surface in TikZ
I am trying to draw a parametric surface using tikz. Here is my code
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        view={180}{50}, 
        hide axis, 
        samples=40, 
        samples y=40, 
        domain=0:360,
        y domain=0:360,
        z buffer=sort, 
    ]
        \addplot3[
            thin,
            surf,
            shader=flat,
            opacity=0.8, 
            mesh/rows=40, 
            mesh/cols=40 
        ]
        (
            {(1.414*cos^2(y)*cos(2*x)+cos(x)*sin(2*y))/(2-1.414*sin(3*x)*sin(2*y))}, 
            {(1.414*cos^2(y)*sin(2*x)-sin(x)*sin(2*y))/(2-1.414*sin(3*x)*sin(2*y))}, 
            {(3*cos^2(y))/(2-1.414*sin(3*x)*sin(2*y))}
        );
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

However, when compiling I get this error
! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '' as a floating point number,sorry. The unreadable part was near ''. (in ' {(1.414cos^2(y)cos(2x)+cos(x)sin(2y))/(2-1.414sin(3x)sin(2y))}').See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... );

Does anyone know how to overcome this issue?
Thank you very much.

The code cos^2(y) does not work. The issue is solved if cos^2(y) is replaced by cos(y)*cos(y) or (cos(y)^2).

It works! I did not know that squares are not allowed. Thanks a lot.
